# How to download a granted Russian patent?

Tags: documents

I want to download a patent granted in Russia. But I am not able to download it from http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/Registers/ website.
Please let me know the correct format to put the patent no. in the provided field.

Answer (score 2):

First, choose a right category for the patent document to be downloaded (patent or patent application, invention or utility model, etc.)
Second, put a registration number into the search field (number only, no RU prefix).
Third, find and click a publication link (usually in the upper left region of the screen); note that earlier publications may not be available in pdf format, so you will have to separately copy text and download images and then combine them in order to get the whole document.
In some cases, only published claims may be found in the registry, not whole document. In such a case you'll have to contact Rospatent with a request for a patent document and pay a corresponding tariff for copying and postal services.
You may also contact a Russian patent attorney who is able to get the document for you (not for free, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try https://worldwide.espacenet.com/ . The european site is very forgiving when entering patent numbers.

Or google patents, they have documents too.